# Список правил для 1440px не работают для 1920px

Tags: html, css, html5, веб-программирование, media-queries

Хей!

---

Верстаю сайт под разные размеры начиная от 1440px до 375px. Все шло хорошо, подправлял именно то, что сползает и тп, но когда я вернулся к 1920px обнаружил, что стили не передаются от 1440px
~
Использую media следующим образом:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1920px) {...}
@media screen and (max-width: 1440px) {...}
@media screen and (max-width: 1280px) {...}
...
```

Если ставлю `@media screen and (min-width: 1440px)`, то все работает, но! Все стили взяты строго из `1440px` и править их не могу

---

Очень долго формулировал вопрос и не уверен в его корректности, так что рад дополнить его в комментариях. Всем спасибо!

UPD: Для 1440px[image: Для 1440px]

Для 1920px[image: Для 1920px]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Прикрепил скрины моей проблемы

Comment: Все верно, так работают @media

Comment: Пример https://jsfiddle.net/n0Lowd8t/1/

Comment: max-width 1440 означает максимальный размер ДО которого будут применены стили.
min-width 1440 означает минимальный размер ОТ которого будут применены стили.
Если верстаете от большего к меньшему (используя max-width), начинайте с самого большого размера.
Либо верстайте mobile first - от меньшего к большему, используя min-width. 
Если вопрос остался, сформулируйте его пожалуйста по-точнее.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для применения стилей для разных условий разделяйте условия запятой:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1440px), 
       screen and (max-width: 1920px) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Про это знаю, но в таком случае его нельзя править для 1920px. Как знаю в media запятая значит логическое выражение "или"

Comment: для 1920px используйте "media screen and (max-width: 1920px) {...}" и ставьте его ниже "media screen and (max-width: 1440px), 
       screen and (max-width: 1920px) {
  ...
}"